# How to find queries that used most memory for sorts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I determine which queries used most memory for sorts/joins/etc?
How can I determine how much memory did one particular query use up?

I was hoping to find something like SET STATISTICS IO ON for an individual query, and a DMV to find out worst offenders, but I could not find any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365393.aspx):

> - `requested_memory_kb`: Total requested amount of memory in kilobytes
> - `granted_memory_kb`: Total amount of memory actually granted in kilobytes.

Comment: I clicked on your link, and the first line was as follows: "Queries that do not have to wait on a memory grant will not appear in this view." What if my query uses a lot of memory but does not wait on a grant? What should I use in this case?

Comment: Any query that requires a memory grant (and thus any query that 'uses lot of memory') will show up. Eg. a simple query like `select ... from table where ...` will not show up because it needs basically no memory at execution. But `select ... from table where ... order by [non-indexed-column]` will show up because it requires a SORT, which needs memory.

Comment: For *general* memory problem investigations, see [DBCC MEMORYSTATUS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907877). Your question though specifically asked about query memory grants.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to find the individual high offender query's and their execution plans

```
-- Find single-use, ad-hoc queries that are bloating the plan cache
SELECT TOP(100) [text], cp.size_in_bytes
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
WHERE cp.cacheobjtype = N'Compiled Plan' 
AND cp.objtype = N'Adhoc' 
AND cp.usecounts = 1
ORDER BY cp.size_in_bytes DESC;
```

furthermore go to [Glen Berry's](https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/?s=diagnostic) blog and and get the full diagnostic script (where I got above).  He has some really great DMV based scripts to find high IO/Mem/CPU queries (AdHoc and SP).

Good Luck

Comment: This finds the largest execution plans in the cache - not those which request the most memory at run time.